# setting width and height of svg image not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

i am trying to load a svg image and set its size like this:

```
var src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74728667/Interstate_75_icon.svg";
var img = new Image(); // don't use document.createElement('image')
img.src = src;
img.style.position = 'absolute';
img.style.left = '0px';
img.style.top = '0px';  
img.style.width='200px';
img.style.height='200px';
var div = document.getElementById("div");
div.appendChild(img);
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/siddjain/1xn706c3/)

it works in chrome but not in ie. how can i make it work in ie as well?

Comment: Which version of IE you're using?

Comment: internet explorer version 11

Comment: Try to add viewBox attribute to source svg document.